# Rotate a character from the character map in word and excel

Tags: fonts, alignment, microsoft-word, microsoft-excel

I'm not sure where to post this question, but I am looking for a "pulled in reverse" character set of the runic alphabet and cannot find one, or how to rotate just a single item. Does anyone know how to get these characters rotated 180 degrees? Or maybe a lowercase caveman d to spell oddhyn.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What do you mean by "pulled in reverse"? And what do you mean by a "caveman d"? Also note that MS Word and Excel are not graphic design software.

Comment: @BillyKerr - I assume they mean to render https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0V9f.jpg as https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnR5E.jpg [no attempt made to clean those up;)

Answer (score 0):

No answer, but a partial workaround.

I tried it as WordArt. One can really remove those bizarre distortions, scale a WordArt object to the right size and also rotate it. WordArt objects can be a part of the text. But making it to fit in the text is painful even in case one has the right font. I haven't one so I tried something else.

In theory you can build an image which contains the wanted word or single letter as a vector drawing. Using WordArt is essentially the same, but the available adjustments are extremely inflexible. Making it is easy only in proper vector drawing programs like Inkscape or Illustrator:

[image]

The text above has 12pt font. I drew my rough viking d to the wanted size, but if I had your font I would simply outline it and rotate 180 degrees and maybe stretched it to the wanted size. This is in Illustrator. There term "outline" means "convert to curves".

In MS Word I can write something with 12 pt font, delete the original d letter and paste in the text writing mode the new image instead. Word accepts inline images. They follow the text movements in later edits like real text. But their sizes stay. In the next image the rough d is copied to the clipboard in Illustrator and pasted to the text in Word:

[image]

I said "a partial workaround", because this works in Word, it doesn't work in Excel nor Powerpoint and pasting it from Word to Excel or Powerpoint doesn't work. But I do not have the latest versions, so it may be useful to try them.

The colors in the screenshot are a warning. Word believes I cannot spell anything right. I'm afraid someone says soon "No worry, you also know nothing of typesetting!"

Comment: [How to change the language setting for proofing and spell check in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/check-spelling-and-grammar-in-a-different-language-667ba67a-a202-42fd-8596-edc1fa320e00)

Comment: Thanks. I need it next time when I want to try to write something in Vikingese.